# How to get paper-radio-button, paper-checkbox or core-dropdown-menu values with PHP $_GET after submitting a form

Tags: php, checkbox, drop-down-menu, radio-button, polymer

I am using **PHP** as a programmation language adapting the MVC architecture.
and the **Polymer** library as a view.

I found some problems particularly when I used some **polymer elements** in a **form**.

If I use the **paper-radio-button**, **paper-checkbox** or **core-dropdown-menu**, for example,

I can not fetch them with $ _GET or $ _POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements you mentioned don't function like normal form elements. You would have to bind their values to a hidden field:

```
<paper-checkbox checked?="{{isChecked}}"></paper-checkbox>
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="{{isChecked}}">
```

Or otherwise serialize/aggregate the values from them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you please explain me how to serialize/aggregate the values from them ?